# In Futurama, why does Nixon howl?

Tags: futurama

Is this some kind of callback to Watergate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The voice actor for the character, Billy West, once stated he does the howl because Nixon reminded him of a werewolf... I personally don't see the resemblance though.